# How to create a service scope using a sharepoint url passed in from an spfx property pane value

Tags: spfx-webparts, pnpjs, service

I'm using the service template found in the PnP JS documentation:

```
export class SampleService {

    public static readonly serviceKey: ServiceKey<ISampleService> = ServiceKey.create<ISampleService>('SPFx:SampleService', SampleService);
    private _sp: SPFI;

    constructor(serviceScope: ServiceScope) {

        serviceScope.whenFinished(() => {

        const pageContext = serviceScope.consume(PageContext.serviceKey);

        //SharePoint
        this._sp = spfi().using(spSPFx({ pageContext }));

    }

    public getLists(): Promise<any[]> {
        return this._sp.web.lists();
    }
}
```

When setting up this._sp = spfi().using(spSPFx({ pageContext })) I'd like to pass in the context of another url (provided from one of the webpart's property pane fields) that's from a different site. How would I set that up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do the servicescope part. But if im understanding correctly, you need to get the WEB object from a different site than the one your are currently using.

You can do it this way by casting a new WebObject based on your current web context + the new sitecollection url:

```
var newWeb = Web(this.sp.web,"newfullurl")
var OtherWebLists = newWeb.lists()
```

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing good documentation on that, but it's the creating a new service scope using the context of another site url that I'm struggling with.